# ¿Cómo implementar notificaciones del navegador web, con Javascript, Ajax y PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Quiero hacer que me sitio muestre notificaciones, hacer aparecer el cuadro de diálogo, pidiendo permiso al usuario para enviarle notificaciones, ya sea de artículos nuevos, mensajes privados o nuevos eventos.
Cómo podría lograrlo mediante `Ajax` y `PHP`.

[image: como puedo lograr hacer esto]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a los botones? Por favor explica mejor tu pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: no, me refiero a las notificaciones.

Comment: esfuérzate un poco más en explicar tu objetivo, tu enfoque de solución, el código que has intentado, y el problema en concreto que has encontrado.

Comment: listo, espero se entienda mejor.

Comment: nuevamente lo edite, espero ahora sí entiendan y disculpen las molestias.

Comment: tu post es muy confuso. ¿Te refieres a cómo implementar notificaciones en el navegador? o a cómo mandar ("push") notificaciones del servidor al navegador?. Investiga un poco más (pista: mírate https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification y https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology ) y regresa aquí con una pregunta más concreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adaptado del artículo de [Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API):

```
// Pedir el permiso
Notification.requestPermission();

// Utilidad para lanzar la notificación
function spawnNotification(theBody,theIcon,theTitle) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon
  }
  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
  setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 5000); 
}

// Lanzar la notificación
spawnNotification("Esto es el cuerpo", undefined, "Título");
```

Se puede ver funcionando [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/dgonz64/hofmtv4g/).

Comment: Nota: Esto es un ejemplo muy simplificado y hay muchas cosas que comprobar si la prueba funciona y se quiere ir en serio. Recomiendo leer el artículo de moz dev.

Comment: gracias, por tu ayuda.